# How to make ElasticSearch fields NON-searchable

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch Version: 6.2.3
How can we make few fields in document NON-searchable.

Answer (score 2):

Check here [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html)

In your mapping a field can have an `index` boolean attribute. Set it to `false` to not index this field, thus make it not searchable.

example :

```
... 
myNonSearchableField: {
    type: "keyword",
    index: false,
}
...
```